# Transparent alpha channel not working on imported .tif files

Tags: import, transparency

I'm trying to import a series of .tif images as planes but I can't get the alpha channel to work. During the import process the Alpha channel box is checked and set to "straight". Under the materials tab the Blend mode is set to "Alpha Blend". However the result (see picture) does not use the transparent alpha channel and instead displays it as white. I have spent hours and hours trying to figure out what seems like a very simple problem, it is driving me crazy. It doesn't work for eevee or cycles. When I open any of the images in photoshop the alpha channel is transparent and clearly exists.

[image]